# Swift equivalent of Python slice assignment

Tags: python, arrays, swift, performance, swift2

In Python, one can have a list (similar to an array in swift):

```
>>> li=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

And perform a slice assignment on any / all of the list:

```
>>> li[2:]=[99]         # note then end index is not needed if you mean 'to the end'
>>> li
[0, 1, 99]
```

Swift has a *similar* slice assignment (this is in the `swift` interactive shell):

```
  1> var arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
arr: [Int] = 6 values {
  [0] = 0
  [1] = 1
  [2] = 2
  [3] = 3
  [4] = 4
  [5] = 5
}
  2> arr[2...arr.endIndex-1]=[99]
  3> arr
$R0: [Int] = 3 values {
  [0] = 0
  [1] = 1
  [2] = 99
}
```

So far, so good. But, there are a couple of issues.

First, swift does not work for an empty list or if the index is after the `endIndex`. Python appends if the slice index is after then end index:

```
>>> li=[]             # empty
>>> li[2:]=[6,7,8]
>>> li
[6, 7, 8]
>>> li=[0,1,2]
>>> li[999:]=[999]
>>> li
[0, 1, 2, 999]
```

The equivalent in swift is an error:

```
  4> var arr=[Int]()
arr: [Int] = 0 values
  5> arr[2...arr.endIndex-1]=[99]
fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start
```

That is easy to test and code around.

Second issue is the killer: it is really slow in swift. Consider this Python code to to perform exact summations of a list of floats:

```
def msum(iterable):
    "Full precision summation using multiple floats for intermediate values"
    # Rounded x+y stored in hi with the round-off stored in lo.  Together
    # hi+lo are exactly equal to x+y.  The inner loop applies hi/lo summation
    # to each partial so that the list of partial sums remains exact.
    # Depends on IEEE-754 arithmetic guarantees.  See proof of correctness at:
    # www-2.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/papers/robust-arithmetic.ps

    partials = []               # sorted, non-overlapping partial sums
    for x in iterable:
        i = 0
        for y in partials:
            if abs(x) < abs(y):
                x, y = y, x
            hi = x + y
            lo = y - (hi - x)
            if lo:
                partials[i] = lo
                i += 1
            x = hi
        partials[i:] = [x]
    return sum(partials, 0.0)
```

It works by maintaining a hi/lo partial summations so that `msum([.1]*10)` produces `1.0` exactly rather than `0.9999999999999999`. The C equivalent of `msum` is part of the [math library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum) in Python.

I have attempted to replicate in swift:

```
func msum(it:[Double])->Double {
    // Full precision summation using multiple floats for intermediate values 
    var partials=[Double]()
    for var x in it {
        var i=0
        for var y in partials{
            if abs(x) < abs(y){
                (x, y)=(y, x)
            }
            let hi=x+y
            let lo=y-(hi-x)
            if abs(lo)>0.0 {
                partials[i]=lo
                i+=1
            }
            x=hi
        }
        // slow part trying to replicate Python's slice assignment partials[i:]=[x]
        if partials.endIndex>i {
            partials[i...partials.endIndex-1]=[x]
        }
        else {
            partials.append(x)
        }    
    } 
    return partials.reduce(0.0, combine: +)
}
```

Test the function and speed:

```
import Foundation
var arr=[Double]()
for _ in 1...1000000 {
    arr+=[10, 1e100, 10, -1e100]
    }

print(arr.reduce(0, combine: +))    // will be 0.0
var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime!
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
print(msum(arr), arr.count*5)          // should be arr.count * 5
print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime)
```

On my machine, that takes 7 seconds to complete. Python native `msum` takes 2.2 seconds (about 4x faster) and the library `fsum` function takes 0.09 seconds (almost 90x faster)

I have tried to replace `partials[i...partials.endIndex-1]=[x]` with `arr.removeRange(i..<arr.endIndex)` and then appending. Little faster but not much.

Question:

1. Is this idiomatic swift: `partials[i...partials.endIndex-1]=[x]`
2. Is there a faster / better way?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious: Did you compile the Swift code in Release configuration? It takes about 1 second on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: @MartinR: (head slap) -- yes that makes a HUGE difference. Now .80 secs or 10x faster. I am surprised at the magnitude of the change.

Comment: Swift 4 now has support for partial ranges. `array[i...]`, `array[..<i]`, and `array[...i]` function like Python's `array[i:]`, `array[:i]`, and `array[:i+1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First (as already said in the comments), there is a huge
difference between non-optimized and optimised code in Swift
("-Onone" vs "-O" compiler option, or Debug vs. Release configuration), so for performance test make sure that the "Release" configuration
is selected. ("Release" is also the default configuration if you 
profile the code with Instruments).

It has some advantages to use *half-open ranges*:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
arr[2 ..< arr.endIndex] = [99]
print(arr) // [0, 1, 99]
```

In fact, that's how a range is stored internally, and it allows you
to insert a slice *at the end* of the array (but not beyond that as in Python):

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr[0 ..< arr.endIndex] = [99]
print(arr) // [99]
```

So

```
if partials.endIndex > i {
    partials[i...partials.endIndex-1]=[x]
}
else {
    partials.append(x)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
 partials[i ..< partials.endIndex] = [x]
 // Or: partials.replaceRange(i ..< partials.endIndex, with: [x])
```

However, that is not a performance improvement. It seems that 
replacing a slice is slow in Swift. Truncating the array and
appending the new element with

```
partials.replaceRange(i ..< partials.endIndex, with: [])
partials.append(x)
```

reduced the time for your test code from about 1.25 to 0.75 seconds on my
computer.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and insight. Helps me on the path of learning the language. I like a lot so far...

Comment: @dawg: Thank *you* – I didn't know that summation method before, so I learned something new today!

Answer (score 4):

As @MartinR points out, `replaceRange` is faster than slice assignment.

If you want maximum speed (based on my tests), your best bet is probably:

```
partials.replaceRange(i..<partials.endIndex, with: CollectionOfOne(x))
```

`CollectionOfOne` is faster than `[x]` because it just stores the element inline within the struct, rather than allocating memory like an array.

Comment: You are right (as always!) – reduces time from 0.75 to 0.68 seconds in my test.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! This did increase the speed also.